# CMS page Header alignment issue

Tags: magento-1.9, cms, header, cms-pages

My cms page :

content:

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="list-group-item list-group-item-success"><h1>giri.in</h1></div>
        <div class="row jumbotron" style="padding-left: 10px;">

            <div class="col" >

                <button type="button" class="btn btn-fb"><i class="fa fa-facebook left"></i> Facebook</button>
            </div>

            <div class="col">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-tw"><i class="fa fa-twitter left"></i> Twitter</button>
            </div>

            <div class="col">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-ins"><i class="fa fa-instagram left"></i> Instagram</button>
            </div>

            <div class="col">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-pin"><i class="fa fa-pinterest left"></i> Pinterest</button>
            </div>        

            <div class="col">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-yt"><i class="fa fa-youtube left"></i> Youtube</button>
            </div>
        </div>   

        <div class="list-group-item list-group-item-success"><h1>giriusa.com</h1></div>

        <div class="row jumbotron" style="padding-left: 10px;">
            <div class="col">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-fb"><i class="fa fa-facebook left"></i> Facebook</button>
            </div>

            <div class="col">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-tw"><i class="fa fa-twitter left"></i> Twitter</button>
            </div>

            <div class="col">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-ins"><i class="fa fa-instagram left"></i> Instagram</button>
            </div>

            <div class="col">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-pin"><i class="fa fa-pinterest left"></i> Pinterest</button>
            </div>        

            <div class="col">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-yt"><i class="fa fa-youtube left"></i> Youtube</button>
            </div>

        </div> 
        <div class="list-group-item list-group-item-success"><h1>giriaus.com</h1></div>

        <div class="row jumbotron" style="padding-left: 10px;">
            <div class="col">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-fb"><i class="fa fa-facebook left"></i> Facebook</button>
            </div>

            <div class="col">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-tw"><i class="fa fa-twitter left"></i> Twitter</button>
            </div>

            <div class="col">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-ins"><i class="fa fa-instagram left"></i> Instagram</button>
            </div>

            <div class="col">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-pin"><i class="fa fa-pinterest left"></i> Pinterest</button>
            </div>        

            <div class="col">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-yt"><i class="fa fa-youtube left"></i> Youtube</button>
            </div>

        </div>     
    </div>
```

Content -> Layout Update XML :

```
<reference name="head">
    <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/social/bootstrap.min.css</name><params/></action>
    <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/social/compiled.min.css</name><params/></action>
    <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/social/font-awesome.min.css</name><params/></action>

    <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/fonts/FontAwesome.otf</name><params/></action>
    <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2</name><params/></action>
   <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff</name><params/></action>
    <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf</name><params/></action>
    <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg</name><params/></action>
    <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot</name><params/></action>

    <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/font/roboto/Roboto-Regular.woff2</name><params/></action>
    <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/font/roboto/Roboto-Regular.woff</name><params/></action>
    <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/font/roboto/Roboto-Regular.ttf</name><params/></action>
    <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/font/roboto/Roboto-Light.woff2</name><params/></action>
    <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/font/roboto/Roboto-Light.woff</name><params/></action>
    <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/font/roboto/Roboto-Light.ttf</name><params/></action>
</reference>
```

In my custom cms page Header alignment collapsed.

Comment: Can you please share screenshot?

Comment: @KKR Home page -> https://snag.gy/KgfUpN.jpg     CMS page -> https://snag.gy/bGDhnm.jpg

Comment: It seems like it is issue of css.
can you please check css of header for both pages.

Comment: @KKR How to add bootstrap in cms page. My custom cms page ready, looking good in system view, how to add bootstrap?

Comment: you need to add bootstrap to your project so that you can able to use its properties.

Comment: Just now i add all bootstrap css files into skin/frond/default/theme/css/bootstrap how can i call in cms page?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96751/discussion-between-zus-and-kkr).